# Nagios 4.0.7 upgrade thrown an error: "Unable to get process status"

Tags: nagios

I have upgraded my `nagios core` to `4.0.7` and there are some errors when I log in my nagios web interface.

First, there is an error message on the home page: `Unable to get process status`.

Second, `nagios` seem not being able to execute any of it's plugin commands which reflects over the `localhost : check_ping` command returning the following status information: `(No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/opt/nagios/nagios/libexec/check_ping, ...) failed. errno is 2: No such file or directory`.

The problem is obvious here, it tries to execute the plugin commands from a wrong directory. After upgrading, all plugin commands are located in `/usr/local/nagios/libexec`. How do I tell `nagios` where to look for default commands?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For others who end up here, the solution for me was that the files in /usr/local/nagios/sbin had the wrong permissions.  Setting them to 755 solved it.

Answer (score 1):

inside `/etc/nagios` there is a `resource.cfg` file which defines the plugins path inside a `$USER1$` variable. Set it to the existing plugins directory, hopefully will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your commands.cfg to the right paths.

[Nagios commands configuration documentation](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#command)

Comment: This would require to change the `commands.cfg` file for all available commands which is not the right way I think. Found a solution however, will post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: 1. The configuration files' existence is to allow platform-specific changes possible. 2. You could always try to symlink the files from the old location to new location, like this: `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but for others who might find it, I had the plugins in a folder different than **/opt/nagios/libexec/**

What fixed it is to copy the plugins from where they were to the folder which Nagios is expecting them to be.

Eg.: **cp -RL /usr/local/nagios/libexec/* /opt/nagios/libexec/**